# Karma Test for Angular 2/4 how to include external library

Tags: angular, charts, karma-jasmine

I have a web app using Angular CLI. And there is a component called pie-chart-component.

In the pie-chart-component.ts, I'm importing Chart.js

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

It works fine from the UI, but when I run `npm test`, it doesn't recognize the  tag in HTML, and fail the basic karma test that comes with Angular CLI that basically test whether this component is created or not.

Error in Karma:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("
  <div style="display: block">
```

part of my spec.ts:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PieChartPanelComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I think I need to add the chart library into providers or imports. But when I try to do that, the compiler will say chart is a type, and I'm trying to use it as a value.

What's the correct way to make Karma test be able to read external libraries and recognize what a  tag is?

Comment: Basically on test you have to recreate the component with all the bindings and dependencies in order to be able to test (mock the ones you cannot reproduce). Take a look at the answer I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811997), maybe you find your answer.

Comment: @BogdanC  to be honest, I know how to include those components that's created internally

Comment: I imagine you should do the same with the external ones. Showing some more code could help also. Are you using ng2-charts?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the ChartsModule then need to import that in spec.ts file also. As follows:

```
import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';
```

And then

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports:[ChartsModule],
    declarations: [PieChartPanelComponent]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```