# Angular 5 karma test showing 'app-addbook' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular5

In /src/app/book, I have the following files - book.component.ts, book.module.ts, book.component.html, book-routing.module.ts, addbook.component.html, addbook.component.ts

My book.component.html has the following codes;

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="addButton()">Add Book</button>
    <div *ngIf="toggleFlag">
      <app-addbook></app-addbook>
    </div>
```

My book.module.ts has the following code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BookRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BookComponent,
    AddbookComponent
  ],
  providers: [BookService]
})
export class BookModule { }
```

My book-routing.module.ts has the below codes:

```
const bookRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'addbook',
    component: AddbookComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(bookRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class BookRoutingModule {
}
```

The application run well; However, when I ran the command `ng test` , it show me that:

> Failed: Template parse errors: 'app-addbook' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-addbook' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-addbook' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message. ("btn btn-outline-success"
>      (click)="addButton()">Add Book
>      `<div *ngIf="toggleFlag">`
>        [ERROR ->]`<app-addbook></app-addbook>`
>      `</div>`

**UPDATE ---**

My **book.component.spec.ts** is below:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BookComponent } from './book.component';

describe('BookComponent', () => {
  let component: BookComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BookComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BookComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: What does your unit test spec file contain?

Comment: @R.Richards - question updated.

Comment: are you sure that the selector is app-addbook if yes restart your server and check again

Comment: I think we really need to see the spec for the `book.component`. The spec you added is for a service.

Comment: @R.Richards - Sorry! question again updated. Kindly check.

Comment: @FatehMohamed - yes, the selector is app-addbook mentioned in the addbook.component.ts

Comment: Start by adding the `AddbookComponent` in the `declarations` section of the book.component spec. There is a good chance you will have to add other things to the spec as you troubleshoot this. You have changed things in the application, so the specs need to change too.

Comment: @R.Richards can you write the same as your answer with some more explanation/ codes etc?

Comment: Did that fix the issue? I was thinking that was only the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170288/discussion-between-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara-and-r-richards).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Karma Test 'component-name' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504468/angular-2-karma-test-component-name-is-not-a-known-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by adding the `AddbookComponent` in the `declarations` section of the *book.component* spec file. See below.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AddbookComponent} from './addbook.component'; 

import { BookComponent } from './book.component';

describe('BookComponent', () => {
let component: BookComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<BookComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ BookComponent, AddbookComponent ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    ...
});
```

There is a good chance you will have to add other things to the spec as you troubleshoot this. You have changed things in the application, so the specs need to be updated as a result.

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/testing) is a good resource for Angular testing techniques.