# Why this Jasmine unit test always fail (testing an Angular component) also if the output returned by my method is correct?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-unit-test

first time for me trying debugging an Angular project with **Jasmine**.

I have this **PeopleListComponent** component class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

interface WorkShiftTypes {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  templateUrl: './people-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people-list.component.css']
})
export class PeopleListComponent implements OnInit {

  people: any[];

  //cities: City[];

  workShiftTypes: WorkShiftTypes[];
  selectedShift: WorkShiftTypes;

  @ViewChild('draggable_people') draggablePeopleExternalElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventService.getPeople().then(people => {this.people = people;});

    this.selectedShift = {name: 'Mattina', value: 'Mattina'};

    this.workShiftTypes = [
      {name: 'Mattina', value: 'Mattina'},
      {name: 'Pomeriggio', value: 'Pomeriggio'},
      {name: 'Notte', value: 'Notte'},
      {name: 'Custom', value: 'Custom'}
    ];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("PEOPLE LIST ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")
    var self = this

    new Draggable(this.draggablePeopleExternalElement.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        console.log("DRAG !!!");
        //console.log("SELECTED SHIFT: " + self.selectedShift.value);
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          startTime: "17:00",
          duration: { hours: 8 }
        };
      }
    });

  }

  createEventObject() {
    console.log("createEventObject() START");
    return 1;
  }

}
```

As you can see it contains this simple method that, at the moment, simply returns the value 1:

createEventObject() {
    console.log("createEventObject() START");
    return 1;
  }

I want to create a very simple Jasmine unit test asserting that the returned value from this method is 1. So I have implemented this **people-list.component.spec.ts** file:

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PeopleListComponent } from "./people-list.component"
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('people-list', () => {
    let component: PeopleListComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PeopleListComponent>;
    let eventServiceSpy : jasmine.SpyObj<EventService>;
        beforeEach(async(() => {
          const eventServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('EventService',['getPeople'])

          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [PeopleListComponent],
              imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
              providers : [{ provide : EventService, useValue : eventServiceSpyObj }]

        });

        // Create a testing version of my PeopleListComponent:
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PeopleListComponent);
        //eventServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(EventService);
        eventServiceSpy = <jasmine.SpyObj<EventService>><any>TestBed.inject(EventService);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('createEventObject()  return 1', () => {
        console.log("TEST 1 START");
        var methodOutput = component.createEventObject();
        console.log("METHOD OUTPUT: " + methodOutput);
        expect(methodOutput).toBe(1);
        //expect(1).toBe(1);
    })
})
```

As you can see I have also inserted some **console.log()** statement into the test arrow function to check the output of the called **component.createEventObject()** and it is correctly return 1.

The problem is that the test fail and I can't understand why.

In the console I am obtaining this error message:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~/Documents/Angular-WS/SOC-Calendar$ ng test
10% building 2/2 modules 0 active23 05 2020 09:27:06.907:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
23 05 2020 09:27:06.916:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.5 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
23 05 2020 09:27:06.920:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
23 05 2020 09:27:06.927:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
23 05 2020 09:27:12.013:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
23 05 2020 09:27:12.211:INFO [Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket 0_E-_vH-y-N_pe-NAAAA with id 36927658
WARN: ''p-selectButton' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-selectButton' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-selectButton' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
WARN: ''p-selectButton' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-selectButton' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-selectButton' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to supWARN: ''p-orderList' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-orderList' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-orderList' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
WARN: ''p-orderList' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-orderList' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-orderList' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppreLOG: 'TEST 1 START'
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'createEventObject() START'
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'METHOD OUTPUT: 1'
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64) people-list createEventObject()  return 1 FAILED
    Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at <Jasmine>
        at PeopleListComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/people-list/people-list.component.ts:29:34)
        at callHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4770:1)
        at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4734:1)
        at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4674:1)
        at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11998:1)
        at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:12114:1)
        at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13668:1)
        at detectChangesInRootView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13702:1)
        at RootViewRef.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:15420:1)
        at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:331:1)
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.055 secs)
Chrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64) people-list createEventObject()  return 1 FAILED
    Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at <Jasmine>
        at PeopleListComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/people-list/people-list.component.ts:29:34)
        at callHook (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4770:1)
        at callHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4734:1)
        at executeInitAndCheckHooks (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4674:1)
        at refreshView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11998:1)
        at renderComponentOrTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:12114:1)
        at tickRootContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13668:1)
        at detectChangesInRootView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13702:1)
        at RootViewRef.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:15420:1)
        at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/tChrome 81.0.4044.129 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.105 secs / 0.055 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS
```

I also tried to replace:

```
expect(methodOutput).toBe(1);
```

with:

```
expect(1).toBe(1);
```

to ensure the test success but I still obtain the same error so I think that the problem is not related to this **excpect-toBe** line but in some configuration of my test.

Why am I obtaining this strange error? What it exactly means? What is wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Karma Test 'component-name' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504468/angular-2-karma-test-component-name-is-not-a-known-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several problems that could be described as the testing module is not configured properly.

- The component contains several dependencies. Like `p-selectButton`, `p-orderList`, etc. Angular tries to resolve those and failed. Workaround - tell the Angular to avoid resolving those tags.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
});
```

- The `fixture.detectChanges()` triggers component lifecycle events. `ngOnInit` among of those. And the error happens there:

```
    Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at <Jasmine>
        at PeopleListComponent.ngOnInit
```

There is only one `then` inside `ngOnInit`.

```
this.eventService.getPeople().then(people => {this.people = people;});
```

Now let's look into the provided mock:

```
const eventServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('EventService',['getPeople'])
{ provide : EventService, useValue : eventServiceSpyObj }
```

It seems like the created spy `eventServiceSpyObj` has the method `getPeople()`. Reading the error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` it is obvious that `getPeople()` return `undefined` instead of Promise. To deal with this issue you need to mock the the return value for `getPeople`

```
const eventServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('EventService',['getPeople'])
eventServiceSpyObj.getPeople.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
```

or don't call the method `fixture.detectChanges()`. It is not needed for this test.